# PhpStorm: Notes Plugin

Tags: php, svn, intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am looking for a plugin in PhpStorm to take notes in a file.

Often I forget important informations (like: What I did, why I did this or which ticket id is assigned to the code) in a file, as these things are not discussed and committed until weeks later.

So it would be nice if there is a plugin which allowed me to take notes for a file. Only local and only for me.

Before you ask me why I don't use PHP Comments (`//`, `/**/`): We use SVN in our team and we don't like it to find personal comments and notes in the whole code...

Is there a plugin / function for me? I can't find any...

Comment: Asking for plugin recommendations is off-topic for SO.

Comment: Try on their forums instead: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200367219-PhpStorm

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Quick Notes for IntelliJ IDEA](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/4456-quick-notes) plugin. But note that it's a bit old, not sure if it's compatible with the most recent IDE versions

Comment: I alredy tried this one. But it did not work for my version.